# Simulating python's "in" in C++

Tags: python, c++, templates, operator-overloading

I managed figure out exact syntax like in python (checking if value is present in container), so you can just check if value is "in" any container that supports `begin()`/`end()` methods.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct specified {
    specified(T const& value) : value_(value) {}
    T value_;

    template<class Container>
    bool operator * (Container const& cont) {
        return (std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value_) != cont.end());
    }

};

struct general {
    template<class T>
    friend specified<T> operator *(T const& rhs, general const&) {
        return specified<T>(rhs);
    }
};

#define in * general() *

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    std::cout << 1 in vec << std::endl;
    std::cout << 4 in vec << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b085ecbfa831428c)

My question is, does it have any pitfalls? Is it safe?

EDIT:

[Support for string literals](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e2ca5b195a4db0a)

Comment: It uses `#define`, not recommended for anything other than conditional compilation. And redefines a potentially common identifier.

Comment: the problem i see is that to understand what is the meaning of `1 in vec` I first have to read and understand your code. On the other hand, `std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value_) != cont.end()` is clear to anybody that knows the std algorithms

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, I was using hard-coded `std::find` all the time. And that's exactly why I tried to create "in" syntax. Writing all the time `std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value_) != cont.end()` is like reinventing wheel again and again each time you have to check something's existence in container. Even custom function like `template<typename V, typename C> bool in(V const& v, C const& c) {...}` would be better (but from your point you still would have to understand this function anyway), but I wanted to take this step further :)

Comment: If you are concerned about too much typing then you could use code templates in your IDE, but, to stay with your analogy, you dont need to invent a bycicle that may fall apart on slightest stress when all you need is a wheel

Comment: I can completely understand your intention, I had a phase myself where I thought it is cool to use macros to decrease amount of typing. However, you have to be aware that the code you are writing isnt just C++ anymore and even you will have a hard time to understand what is going on once you encounter some strange edge case or pitfall that you didnt consider before.

Comment: @tobi303 Well, I use only those macros that I consider very safe. Right now I have 7, maybe 8 usefull macros because rest of them had pitfalls or could be replaced (mostly by template metaprogramming). For me macros are last resort if something can't be implemented with just non-preprocessed code. Passing template functions/variables as function arguments, implemnting fluent interface wrapper without repeating type name, mapping enums to strings, debug macros. Preprocessor is great when used wisely :)

Comment: One idea: you can get rid of the macro and use ["named operators"](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator), although in this case your code will look like something `if x <in> vec`, with the additional comparison signs. I also think the example in the repo has exactly your case covered, see the bottom of https://github.com/klmr/named-operator/blob/master/example.cpp

Comment: @vsoftco Wow. That's nice usage of operator overloading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a small workaround for strings.

Doesn't work as expected with string literals.

```
std::vector<string> vec{"1","2","3"};
std::cout << "1" in vec << std::endl;
std::cout << "4" in vec << std::endl;
```

This code results in compile-time error.

```
error: array used as initializer
  specified(T const& value) : value_(value) {}
```

C++ takes the string literals as `char[]` instead of taking it as `string`. So we need to explicitly mention it.

```
std::cout << string("1") in vec << std::endl;
```

Comment: Good point. I edited question to add support for string literals, but your answer is very valid.

Answer (score 1):

No it isnt safe, because you are using `#define`. Adding a completely harmless looking line

```
void foo(int in) { }
```

just before your main, [will break the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bf067649c483947). In this case the error message is quite clear, but in general it isnt.

I know it is very tempting to introduce new syntax and cool stuff, but using macros isnt the way to go. Anyhow, to be honest if I had to work with your code I would prefer to see a

```
 std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value_) != cont.end()
```

where I know what it means by looking at only that line instead of a

```
value_ in cont
```

for which I would have to study some code to really understand what it means.

Comment: I really thought I could use it in competitive coding. :(

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak ? what do you mean? competetive coding is a completely different story. In coding competetions you are often pushed into using dirty stuff that you would never use in real code

Comment: I know it is different domain. But it is faster to type `1 in cont` than `std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), 1) != cont.end()`.

Comment: most IDEs have code templates that one can use, though i have little experience becuase I dont mind typing a bit more