# How can I check equality with one of a set of values?

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to use an `if` statement that looks something like this:

```
if (input == Positive)
{
    // Do something
}
```

To be actually doing something that looks like this:

```
if (input == "yes" ||input ==  "Yes" ||input ==  "YES" ||input ==  "Ya" ||input ==  "ya" (etc all the rest of positive words/ways to say yes))
{
    // Do something
}
```

I was thinking I would keep my code in a static library (though I don't know much about them so feel free to correct me if there is a better way) so that I can access it from any future program I use and I don't have to copy-paste this same code over and over. Is there any way to do this? Or something similar to this?

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: Just to mention few: you may also consider `if (isPositive(input))` but if that's not what you reeaaally want then you might create an `Input` class (let's say) with an overloaded `==` operator (and `Positive` has to be an instance of that class). Note that if you have a list `std::vector<string>` of words then a simple `find()` might do.

Comment: @Habitate C++ can't `switch` on non-integral types.

Comment: @Quentin oh yeah, totaly forgot

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Solution is the C++ way to do this.  Put the code you don't want to repeat in a function, and then call that function when needed.  You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020246/simulating-pythons-in-in-c) to make it Pythony but it can/will cause you issues later on down the road.

Comment: Note that achieving the syntax you wish for, and wrapping that in a reusable component are two different questions. The latter depends on which C++ toolchain you are using, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: You can use regular expression to solve this problem statement.

Comment: @phuclv, that applies to integers rather than strings - the bitmasking solutions there aren't applicable here.

Comment: @TobySpeight there are various solutions there. And of course there are countless number of duplicates: [C++ multiple strings inside an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43484761/995714), [Check for multiple values when using comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11583592/995714), [Check if string is in string (list of strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14515274/995714)

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree, that's why the "reeaally". I'd personally feel confused to see `==` used as `in` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to test for inclusion.  The most natural is to use a set:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
```

```
    static const std::set<std::string> positive_answers =
        { "yes", "Yes", "YES", "Ya", "ya" };

    if (positive_answers.count(input) > 0) {

        // Do something
    }
```

---

Here's a full program version of the above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "YES";

    static const std::set<std::string> positive_answers =
        { "yes", "Yes", "YES", "Ya", "ya" };

    if (positive_answers.count(input) > 0) {
        std::cout << "Agreed\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Disagreed\n";
    }
}
```

---

You might consider using a variadic template:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
bool is_in(T candidate, U... positives)
{
    const std::set<std::string> positive_answers{{positives...}};
    return positive_answers.count(candidate) > 0;
}
```

used like this:

```
    if (is_in(input, "yes", "Yes", "YES", "Ya", "ya"))
```

That can work, but be careful if `input` is a C-style string (`char*`), as that will use a pointer's comparison function.

Comment: You can also use `count` instead of `find` - it returns 1 when found and 0 otherwise. This will avoid the long-winded `== .end()` syntax.

Comment: Of course - thanks!  A set knows that count is at most 1, so there's no inefficiency as there would be with a vector or list.

Comment: Why not an unordered_set?

Comment: @Tharwen - no good reason; either is as good as the other for a small set of alternatives such as this.

Comment: ...on the other hand `count` wont stop counting once it found the first positive, though for 5 elements that shouldnt really matter

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: as I commented, a set's `count()` *does* "stop counting" once it's determined whether or not the item is present in the set.  You may be thinking of the `std::count()` function in `<algorithm>`, which would examine every member of the set.  Don't use that.

Comment: ah sorry, I read anatolygs comment, but understood it only now